# Eclipse: debug shared library loaded from python

Tags: python, debugging, gdb, shared-libraries, eclipse-cdt

In Linux, I am trying to debug the C++ code of a shared library which is loaded from Python code. The loading is done using the `ctypes` package. In Eclipse, I set breakpoints both in the Python and in the C++ code, however Eclipse just skips the breakpoints in the C++ code (breakpoints in the Python code work OK).

I have tried using `attach to application` in Eclipse (under Debug Configurations) and choosing the Python process, but it didn't change anything. In the `attach to application` dialog box I choose the shared library as the Project, and I choose `/usr/bin/python2.6` as the `C/C++ application`. Is that the correct way?

I've tried it both before running the python code, and after a breakpoint in the Python code was caught, just before the line calling a function of the shared library.

**EDIT**

Meanwhile I am using a workaround of calling the python code and debugging using a gdb command-line session by attaching to the python process. But I would like to hear a solution to doing this from within Eclipse.

Comment: Is the library built with debugging information?

Comment: Yes, I can debug the library without any problem when it is loaded from a c++ executable.

Comment: On 2nd thought, how can I verify that the python code loads the debug version?

Comment: GDB should warn if debug info is not found (`Reading symbols from <library>...(no debugging symbols found)...done.` vs. `Reading symbols from <library>...done.`). I'm not familiar with Eclipse; hopefully you have a way to read the raw GDB output.

Comment: try using _asm("int $3") in the c++ code

Answer (score 2):

I have been able to debug the c++ shared library loaded by the python in Eclipse successfully.

The prerequisites:
Two eclipse projects in an eclipse workspace: one is the C++ project, from which the c++ shared library is generated, the other is the python project (PyDev), which loads the generated c++ shared library.

The steps are:

1. create a "**Python Run**" debug configuration named *PythonDebug* with the corresponding python environment and parameters
2. create a "**C/C++ Attach to Application**" debug configuration named *CppDebug*. The project field is the C++ project, leave the **C/C++ Application** field empty
3. set a breakpoint in python code where after the c++ shared library has already been loaded
4. start the debug session *PythonDebug*, the program will be breaked at the created breakpoint at step 3
5. start the debug session *CppDebug*, a menu will be popped up, select python process with correct pid (there will be 3 pids, the correct one can be found in PythonDebug session)
6. set a breakpoint in c++ source code where you want the program to break
7. continue the *PythonDebug* session
8. continue the *CppDebug* session
9. the program will break at the c++ breakpoint

I tested the above procedure with Eclipse Mars version.

Hopefully it helps.

Comment: I was able to debug the python+c++ shared library project with the similar procedure with MingW. There are two differences: 1. I had to select the "Legacy Attach to Process Launcher". 2. The C/C++ Applications field should not be empty, but the python executable.